# Easy Way to Create Trellis Plots in Mathematica

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to do multivariate statistical analysis on a data set and I'd like to quickly visualize my information first using Trellis-like plots. For example, I'd like to create scatterplots for body mass and height separated by region.

I'm currently creating all the graphs individually and then displaying them together with GraphicsGrid but I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing it.

Comment: Pls check if `PairwiseScatterPlot` in `StatisticalPlots` package fits your needs.

Comment: There's also a [version on a New-in-V8 page](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/statistical-visualization/compare-multiple-datasets.html) that contains a lot of tricks for making this sort of thing look nice.

Comment: I'm familiar with the PairwiseScatterPlot function but unfortunately in this case it doesn't work since the habitat, the 3rd variable, is categorical. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you are doing, but just in case:

```
t = Table[{RandomChoice[{"Reg1", "Reg2", "Reg3"}], 
    RandomReal[{10, 20}], RandomReal[{50, 70}]}, {i, 1, 10}];
sel[x_] := Select[t, #[[1]] == "Reg" <> ToString[x] &];
plt[x_] := ListLinePlot[#] &@(sel[x][[All, 2 ;; 3]]);

pltR = Flatten[Options[plt[#], PlotRange] & /@ Range[3] /. 
              HoldPattern[PlotRange -> x_] -> x, 1];
pltRR = {{Min@pltR[[All, 1, 1]],  Max@pltR[[All, 1, 2]]}, 
         {Min@pltR[[All, 2, 1]],  Max@pltR[[All, 2, 2]]}};

GraphicsGrid[{ListLinePlot[#, PlotRange -> pltRR] &@ (sel[#][[All, 2 ;; 3]]) & 
             /@ Range[3]}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]